# the different when using Case expression in Order by | SQL

Tags: sql

I found a problem in w3resource:

> Write a SQL query to find all the details of 1970 winners by the ordered to subject and winner name; but the list contain the subject Economics and Chemistry at last.

here is the answer:

```
SELECT *
FROM nobel_win
WHERE year=1970 
ORDER BY
 CASE
    WHEN subject IN ('Economics', 'Chemistry') THEN 1
    ELSE 0
 END ASC,
 subject,
 winner;
```

As I understand, the query first divides the *subject* into 2 parts, and then sorting the *subject*, the last is sorting by *winner*

So why when I try to swap Order position like:

```
...
...
ORDER BY
subject,
winner,
 CASE
    WHEN subject IN ('Economics', 'Chemistry') THEN 1
    ELSE 0
 END ASC;
```

I can't get the Economics, Chemistry in the last of list, the query just divides *subject* into 2 parts which always have 'Economics' and 'Chemistry' on top no matter what *THEN a ELSE b (a>b or a<b or a=b)*

the link of problem: https://www.w3resource.com/sql-exercises/sql-retrieve-exercise-24.php

Comment: You should swap the `1` and the `0` in your first query.

Comment: When you put subject up before the case statement you said to alphabetize ALL subjects first, so the case statement became useless.  Your original query puts Economics and Chemistry to the "last of list".  If you want them to be first, change the ASC to DESC.

Comment: `case` _expression_.

Comment: Because `order by` orders by the specified expressions starting from the first one. So all subsequent expressions are used to order identical values of the previous expressions

Comment: @ChrisMaurer I don't think the case statement became useless bc the case statement still divides the subject into (Economics, Chemistry) and the remaining but (Economics, Chemistry) always on top. That's the thing makes me confused

Comment: What I mean by useless - Order By will NEVER  use the second or third expressions until there is an exact match between two records in the first expression, then it will consult the second and the third,  but only as a tiebreaker.   This means your result set will be alphabetized by subject primarily and then winner within that.  When you put your case expression third, you are ordering only those records that have the same subject AND the same winner.  In the history of the Nobel prizes this has only happened 4 times, and it would not change anything because they are all the same subject.